# Preorder transversal of a binary tree is printing out extra values I do not want

Tags: java, recursion, preorder

I have implemented a preorder transversal in Java that prints out the character at each node of a binary tree along with the path represented by 0s and 1s to get to that node. "0" meaning to go down a left path and "1" to go down the right. However, after certain nodes are printed it will print extra path numbers before printing the next character at a different node.
This is my code

```
public static void printCodes(MsgTree root, String code)
    {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        System.out.println("   " + root.payloadChar + "        " + code);

        printCodes(root.left, code + "0");
        
        printCodes(root.right, code + "1");
    }
```

The result should look like

```
a   0
!   100
d   1010
c   1011
r   110
b   111
```

but it instead looks like

```
a   0
    1
    10
!   100
    101
d   1010
c   1011
    11
r   110
b   111
```

I have tried a ton of different things, but nothing seems to work. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you in the same class as this person? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744092/did-i-set-up-this-bst-correctly-if-so-how-can-i-use-it-in-other-methods/62745771

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in your tree (which I recognize from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744092/did-i-set-up-this-bst-correctly-if-so-how-can-i-use-it-in-other-methods/62745771)!) nodes either hold data, or they hold children, but not both.

Look at the second line of the desired output:

```
!   100
```

That means that in order to get to the `!` node, the program had to go right (`1`) then left twice (`00`). So it visited a couple of other nodes in the process of getting to `!` but didn't print them.

You should just check if `payloadChar` is empty and if it is, don't print anything.

By the way, although you didn't include it, I'm pretty sure that your output included a blank line above the first one:

```
(blank line)
a   0 
    1
    10
!   100
```

That would have come from the root node.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried something similar to this, but I couldn't figure out how to check if it is empty because I cannot use "== null" to compare because it is a char. And it says that root.payloadChar can only be null at certain locations?

Comment: When you built the tree, what did you assign to `payloadChar` for the nodes that have children? It can't be `null` because it's a `char` but it might just be plain old `0` (zero) or maybe `' '` (space).

Comment: If you didn't assign anything, it will be `0`.